# $\mathbb{Z}$-points in a given $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$-isomorphism class

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Given a finite type $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme $X$ with $X(\widehat{\mathbb{Z}})\neq\emptyset$ can we find a finite type $\mathbb{Z}$-scheme $Y$ with $X\times \widehat{\mathbb{Z}}\cong Y\times\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$ and $Y(\mathbb{Z})\neq\emptyset$?

Comment: What about $X=\mathbb{A}^1_{\mathbb{Z}}\setminus \{0,1,2\}$?

Comment: If you mean $X=\mathrm{Spec}\:\mathbb{Z}[x, y, z, w]/(xy-1, xz-z-1, xw-2w-1)$ then $X(\mathbb{F}_2)$ is empty.

Comment: What about a smooth projective curve of higher genus, say $C$, over $\mathbb{Q}$ with no automorphisms (over $\mathbb{C}$) and with points everywhere locally? Surely these exist, no?

Comment: Can two non-isomorphic finite type $\mathbb{Z}$-schemes that have only trivial automorphisms after base change to $\mathbb{C}$ become isomorphic after base change to $\widehat{\mathbb{Z}}$? I do not know.

Comment: If $X$ is a (higher genus) smooth  projective curve over $\mathbb{Q}$ with no non-trivial automorphisms, then it has no twists. So, any curve $Y$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ that is isomorphic to it over $\mathbb{C}$ is already isomorphic to it over $\mathbb{Q}$.